# vertical alignment in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. Here is a sample of the code I'm using.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="#" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Those p tags have multiple lines of text. The image that is to the left is much larger than the text area, so I would like those elements to be vertically aligned. Here is what I have tried:

```
1. The table/table-cell trick.
2. The transform/Translatey trick.
3. Setting margin-top to 50% (didn't think that would work).
4. flex and align-items/justify-content.
```

Problem is this, the parent element will not have a height, so every solution I found online and through StackOverflow do not seem to work for me. I appreciate any assistance in this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap those paragraph into `div` then you can use following solution. `col-lg-6` is changed to `col-xs-6` just to show left-right layout in the code snippet.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.middle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row outer">
    <div class="col-xs-6 middle"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f6/16/d0/f616d044c7937dde2e8ec2b4f3e6f79c.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 middle">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <p>Some more text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```